# ORA-00054 while loading large data file

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-loader, ora-00054

I get ORA-00054 while loading large data files(~ 10 gb)
The error occurs when this a new file is loaded after a previous file. 
Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

One possible scenario.

Is this a direct path load ? If so, please check the v$locked_object view and see if is being locked by someone during your load.

```
select dbao.object_name
  from v$locked_object vlo,
       dba_objects dbao
  where vlo.object_id = dbao.object_id
    and dbao.object_name = 'Table that you are trying to load...'
```

From the Oracle Documentation at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c21dlins.htm

> Locking Considerations with
>   Direct-Path INSERT
>
> During direct-path INSERT, Oracle
>   obtains exclusive locks on the table
>   (or on all partitions of a partitioned
>   table). As a result, users cannot
>   perform any concurrent insert, update,
>   or delete operations on the table, and
>   concurrent index creation and build
>   operations are not permitted.
>   Concurrent queries, however, are
>   supported, but the query will return
>   only the information before the insert
>   operation.

Comment: When manually trying to insert concurrently, remove the append hint. This has been for me a commen mistake that can be quickly corrected. The user is to consider performance. You could also do a concurrent direct path insert (with append hint) if you insert directly in individual partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is linked to tablespace datafile sizes, table size, because ORA-00054 usually appears when an ALTER statement is run.

I do not pretend to be right here.

Answer (score 0):

Check those views.

- DBA_BLOCKERS – Shows non-waiting sessions holding locks being waited-on
- DBA_DDL_LOCKS – Shows all DDL locks held or being requested
- DBA_DML_LOCKS  - Shows all DML locks held or being requested
- DBA_LOCK_INTERNAL – Displays 1 row for every lock or latch held or being requested with the username of who is holding the lock
- DBA_LOCKS  - Shows all locks or latches held or being requested
- DBA_WAITERS  - Shows all sessions waiting on, but not holding waited for locks

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00054_locks.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your table seems to be locked: [ORA-00054](http://www.orasite.com/errores/ORA-00054.html)
It can be because of the way that Oracle driver handles the BLOB types (the driver locks the record, opens an stream to write the binary data, and needs "some help" to release the record).
I would try the next secuence:

1. Load the first file
2. COMMIT;
3. Load the second file